# bacula-dir failed at start

Tags: centos, backup, bacula

I want to install/config a backup-server by useing Bacula. 
I've installed and configured everything with the help of 
[Bacula Tutorial](http://webmodelling.com/webbits/miscellaneous/bacula.aspx)

Now I tried to start the bacular director (bacula-dir) but nothing happens.
In debug-mode (bacula-dir -d 200) I get the following output.

```
bacula-dir: dird.c:223-0 Debug level = 200
bacula-dir: jcr.c:140-0 read_last_jobs seek to 192
bacula-dir: jcr.c:147-0 Read num_items=0
bacula-dir: dir_plugins.c:160-0 Load dir plugins
bacula-dir: dir_plugins.c:162-0 No dir plugin dir!
bacula-dir: mysql.c:709-0 db_init_database first time
bacula-dir: mysql.c:177-0 mysql_init done
bacula-dir: mysql.c:202-0 mysql_real_connect done
bacula-dir: mysql.c:204-0 db_user=bacula db_name=bacula db_password=password
bacula-dir: mysql.c:227-0 opendb ref=1 connected=1 db=7fe692baa560
bacula-dir: sql_create.c:357-0 In create mediatype
bacula-dir: sql_create.c:361-0 selectmediatype: SELECT MediaTypeId,MediaType FROM MediaType WHERE MediaType='File'
bacula-dir: mysql.c:249-0 closedb ref=0 connected=1 db=7fe692baa560
bacula-dir: mysql.c:256-0 close db=7fe692baa560
bacula-dir: pythonlib.c:102-0 No script dir. prog=DirStartUp
bacula-dir: dird.c:364-0 Start UA server
bacula-dir: bnet_server.c:112-0 Addresses host[ipv4:193.175.220.151:9101] 
bacula-dir: job.c:1334-0 wstorage=storage1
bacula-dir: job.c:1343-0 wstore=storage1 where=Job resource
bacula-dir: job.c:1034-0 JobId=0 created Job=*JobMonitor*.2017-07-25_12.49.35_01
bacula-dir: dird.c:377-0 wait for next job
bacula-dir: scheduler.c:104-0 Enter wait_for_next_job
bacula-dir: scheduler.c:273-0 enter find_runs()
bacula-dir: scheduler.c:286-0 now = 5977223f: h=12 m=6 md=24 wd=2 wom=3 woy=30
bacula-dir: scheduler.c:303-0 nh = 5977304f: h=13 m=6 md=24 wd=2 wom=3 woy=30
bacula-dir: scheduler.c:312-0 Got job: WebServ1-backup
bacula-dir: scheduler.c:355-0 run@7fe692b84938: run_now=0 run_nh=0
bacula-dir: scheduler.c:355-0 run@7fe692b84a08: run_now=0 run_nh=0
bacula-dir: scheduler.c:355-0 run@7fe692b84ad8: run_now=0 run_nh=0
bacula-dir: scheduler.c:374-0 Leave find_runs()
```

It seems like there is an endless loop because after a few seconds the last 5 lines are starting again.

Can anybody help and tell me what I've done wrong or where I can get more informations about the error?

The server is a centOS 7 64bit.

Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by reconfiguration the director.